# Slower queries after adding INDEX

Tags: performance, sqlite, indexing

Queries looks like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN ... WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 IS NULL ORDER BY ...
```

and

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE col3 IS NULL ORDER BY ...
```

col1, col2 have indexes, but col3 didn't.

I decided to add an index to col3 as well, because queries were a slightly slow, from 0002s to 0.4s per query (all of them take 1.3 seconds):

```
CREATE INDEX col3_idx ...
REINDEX col3_idx;
```

But after this they got much slower. Queries now take 20 seconds.

I thought indexes are supposed to speed up selects :/

I suspect is has something to do with `IS NULL`. Do indexes not work with IS NULL ?

Answer (score 0):

You main problem isn't the NULL it's the fact that you created three distinct indexes as opposed to one.

for the first query, I'd suggest on index on `(col1, col2, col3)`.

However, the second query might be hard to index if you have only NULL/1 values, because it might be better to do a full table scan in that case anyway. But indexing is also related to sorting, hence it would be interesting to see the `ORDER BY` clause too, then it might be possible to define a good index for this query too (maybe even one good index for both queries!).

References:

- [Multi-Column Indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys)
- [Why one index per column isn't the best option](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/index-merge-performance)
- [Indexing `ORDER BY`](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by)